# Is net8.0-tvos ready?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tvos, .net-8.0, xcode15

I am working on migrating our Xamarin.tvos app to .NET 8 (we are using net8.0-tvos), but I am running into a lot of problems.  I have made multiple issues with visual studio support and have not had any luck so far.  Recently, someone commented on one of my issues saying that Microsoft dropped support for tvos and that I'll have to look for the notification that states this.  I have not been able to find anything that says this.  If anyone is able to find this, could you send a link to it?

The migration docs mention setting the runtimeidentifier for tvos, and there are no addendums stating that tvos isn't ready yet.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/apple-projects?view=net-maui-8.0

Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.5 release notes mention adding support for xcode 15.1 and 15.2 and says the release contains tvos 17.2.8004, but I am having the same problems as before.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.8.5
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases

I am leaving links to the VS support tickets in case anyone wants to try to recreate the issues.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/TVOS-device-is-not-shown-in-Visual-Studi/10484220?ref=native&refTime=1705954140087&refUserId=2fbe66df-f924-6d3e-81cf-99721ac92dde

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-getting-pack-version:-Pack-Micros/10489593?ref=native&refTime=1705954140085&refUserId=2fbe66df-f924-6d3e-81cf-99721ac92dde

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Debugging-tvOS-NET-Project-nET-8-or-7/10525345?port=1025&fsid=adfe6d8f-188f-4eb0-a10b-c50ba454a80d&ref=native&refTime=1705954236672&refUserId=7c4918b1-b4ee-6fae-9184-4ac17d9302bf

I created a new .net 8 app using the "tvos application" template in visual studio 2022.  I would like to be able to run a hello world.  The project can build, but when it tries to deploy I get an error that says "There aren't any active launch profiles configured for this project".  Also, if I use xcode 15, my apple tv device does not show up in the list of devices and simulators.

Comment: Have you tried running this in the terminal from the root of your tvos project `dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-tvos` that makes it work for me. You will have to make sure that you have the tvOS SDK installed in Xcode